# Background picture won't stretch below fixed footer

Tags: html, css, background-image, footer, fixed

I recently added a fixed footer to a webpage I'm working on, and for the most part it works great, but on a certain page that has enough text that a scrollbar is included, my background page doesn't stretch below the footer. The problematic page can be found [here](http://budbranchblossom.com/about.html).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "doesn't stretch below the footer"?
I tried the link and it works fine

Comment: Try removing `position:fixed` from footer

Answer (score 0):

You have given:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    }
```

Change it to:

```
html,body{
min-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `height: 100%` from both the `html` and `body` elements. That way the size of the background will stretch all the way down automatically.

You may also want to make the background be at least as tall as the viewport, so put `min-height: 100%` on `html` and `body` elements.